# How to add %like% search functionality in header search Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

When i search "cocacola" product it search 1 product which is "cocacola" but when i search "cola" then no product found. i want search "cola" and it should a product but right now no product found. i want use %like% condition.
I Want to add this functionality in header Search.

**View Example**
 In Magento 1 Search work like https://app.hyfy.io/v/abfCoSnOT5n/
 In Mahento 2 Search work like https://app.hyfy.io/v/ab3EtzbNT5n/
So Magento 2 Search Not Working Like Magento 1.

Comment: Hi Sanket, thank you for posting. Adding examples of what you tried so far, will help a lot. You are currently asking for a whole feature which seldom yields answers

Comment: In magento 1 there are functionality  for search in admin  like , combine and like combine but there are no more option for magento 2 so i can not use like condition for searching product

Answer (score 1):

source : https://alanstorm.com/magento_2_understanding_object_repositories/

I think you are looking for something like this :

Verbose way :

```
//create our filter
$filter = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\Filter');
$filter->setData('field','name');
$filter->setData('value','%coca%');
$filter->setData('condition_type','like');

//add our filter(s) to a group
$filter_group = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroup');
$filter_group->setData('filters', [$filter]);

//add the group(s) to the search criteria object
$search_criteria = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface');
$search_criteria->setFilterGroups([$filter_group]);

//query the repository for the object(s)
$repo = $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');                        
$result = $repo->getList($search_criteria);
$products = $result->getItems();
foreach($products as $product)
{
    echo $product->getSku(),"\n";
}
```

Less verbose :

```
//create our filter
$filter = $this->objectManager
->create('Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder')
->setField('name')
->setConditionType('like')
->setValue('%coca%')
->create();

//add our filter(s) to a group
$filter_group = $this->objectManager
->create('Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder')
->addFilter($filter)
->create();
// $filter_group->setData('filters', [$filter]);

//add the group(s) to the search criteria object
$search_criteria = $this->objectManager
->create('Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder')
->setFilterGroups([$filter_group])
->create();
```

You can find all the condition type here : `vendor/magento/framework/Api/CriteriaInterface.php`

Comment: Thanks for Answer but i am not getting it. Can you explain in detail that in which file and which function i need to add code? Also i am using magento version  2.0.16.

Also there is not any code in "vendor/magento/framework/Api/CriteriaInterface.php" file

Comment: Well give me more explanation of what you need because you ask me to do a full module without giving me any information.. for the version 2.0.16 i think you don't have the repository so you need to use the factory. About the questions where to put the code : In any php function of your module. Just inject the criteria or factory module and its over. Going to give you an example later this week end if i have time

Comment: I want the product collection count by search terms, I tried the above solution but in the PLP page count and the above strategy count returns a different results.